# Scratch Editor installer won't run

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, installation

Recently I had downloaded Scratch Editor 2.0 offline editor, but I couldn't install it. When I click on the .exe file a security dialog box opens and when i click on the run button, the window just goes away and nothing happens. I tried searching on Google to make the file run somehow, but most of the answers are based on Windows 7 and XP, or the solutions don't work. I even downloaded the file for the second time but still it didn't worked.

Is there any registry editing (for Windows 8.1) that would work?
I don't know much how to work with registry but would not hesitate to get my problem solved by it.

or any other solution?

[image: Security warning]

```
   Log Name:      Application
   Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP
   Date:          27/11/2015 12:17:04 PM
   Event ID:      16385
   Task Category: None
   Level:         Error
   Keywords:      Classic
   User:          N/A
   Computer:      win
```

Description:
Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2015-12-27T05:57:04Z. Error Code: 0x80041318.
Event Xml:

   
    
    16385
    0
    2
    0
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    58714
    
    
    Application
    win
    
  
  
    0x80041318
    2015-12-27T05:57:04Z

[Adobe Air Install log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByWCrEzJsRmCbUNVQTJWdllPNWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it must be crashing. Open eventvwr.msc and see the Application log for the error

Comment: Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2015-12-18T09:36:59Z. Error Code: 0x80041318.

Comment: @GaneshR. Also i forgot to mention that whenever i try opening my exe file it gives a security warning dialog.So maybe now it relates somewhat with the error but still how do i resolve it?

Comment: Please post an image of the security warning. Also, The error you mentioned happens on Windows 10 due to timezone being different from default UTC -8.00. It was fixed in August for Windows 10. Do you regualrly update the OS?

Comment: Does that mean that this error gets fixed for Windows 8.1 users too? ...No i really don't update my OS..

Comment: Should. Atleast it did for Windows 10 RTM

Comment: You tried a clean install of scratch right?

Comment: @KiroYakuza no i didn't..  how do i clean install a 'software'?  Please explain?

Comment: @Yashw, a clean install is to uninstall and then reinstall a piece of software in the hopes that doing so will "reset" the software to a default working stage. What that means for you, is that you could go registry digging and try to find the corruption instead of just reinstalling, but would you really want to?

Comment: Have you right clicked on the executable and selected Run as Administrator?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe what happened/happens.  You said, "When I click on the `.exe` file, nothing happens.", but then you added (in a comment) "I forgot to mention that whenever I try opening my exe file it gives a security warning dialog."  (You *forgot*?  … ***maybe*** it relates?)  Do you click on the "Run" button?  Does the "Security Warning" window disappear?  Do you see any hint that the program is starting and crashing (e.g., do you see a flicker of an application window or a task bar button)?  Also, have you tried downloading it again (in case your copy is corrupted)?

Comment: I dare to say that this event you have posted is not directly related to the Scratch behavior you are experiencing. You should nevertheless fix it using this hints http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/failed-to-schedule-software-protection-service-for/94f4c380-9a79-43f7-8457-a98fe92a2746?auth=1  Then also scan your computer for malware (using MBAM etc.). The security warning is absolutely OK.

Comment: @Yashw I guess that Adobe AIR fails to install for you. Try to download and install Adobe AIR separately. See http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_2.0_Offline_Editor - there is a link to Adobe AIR.

Comment: @DaveM yes sir!

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal i reinstalled it but still Scratch isn't opening.

Comment: Check `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Adobe\AIR\logs` path... Why are you running it by clicking on exe and not using installed shortcut?

Comment: I see, so your problem is probably wrongly described, it should be `Cannot install Scratch offline editor` and not `Cannot run Scratch offline editor`. Edit your question so that it is not misleading.

Comment: Did you install from this location? https://scratch.mit.edu/scratch2download/ Also try to disable antivirus temporarily.

Comment: Apoligies for the misleading message..

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I did installed from the same location plus i tried installing after disabling my antivirus but still it didn't work.

Comment: Hm, I have no more ideas without further info from log files, you may try to post your problem on https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/3/

Comment: You shoud by any means include the whole content of `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Adobe\AIR\logs\Install.log`log file to enable further troubleshooting. Scratch installer itself is an AIR appliaction which **requires AIR to be installed before**, so the reason why it does not start is surely connected with Adobe AIR.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal i have uploaded the log file....

Comment: It looks like you have installed AIR ok, then reinstalled. But bootstrapper for Scratch is not launching at all, there is no line `Bootstrapper begin with version 3.9.0.1380 on Windows 8 x86`, which indicates scratch installer launch. Looks like the exe did not start at all. Also no error message that would help.

Comment: It says "cannot open file 'C:\users\win8.1....  .exe' as archive" when i try to extract it.

Comment: 7-zip can surely open the EXE file from that URL, I have  tested it. So the answer is that the downloaded file is corrupted.

Comment: The EXE file should have 64 680 611 bytes.  Google Chrome should be no problem, some antivirus or virus may do somethig wrong, but it is hard to say, it is definitely very strange.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I think google chrome was the main problem. I downloaded the file using internet download manager and it worked, plus i was able to install it without extracting it. But i still wonder because what i have seen google chrome either downloads a file completely or not at all. So if the downloading had been interrupted, the file wouldn't had been there and as i said earlier in my question- i had downloaded the file twice, so i really think there is some problem with my chrome.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal and thank you very much for not giving up on this problem because i had. I was about to format my PC but thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance that this may work for you (if not, I will delete the answer):

Use unzip software like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Open the downloaded .exe file using 7-zip and extract the content of the archive to some newly created empty folder e.g. `C:\Scratch2`.

See that there is a `Scratch 2.exe` file in the extracted folder. If you have Adobe AIR installed  correctly, you can directly run this EXE file and create shortcut manually. You can also try to run `setup.msi` that would eventually install Scratch for you.

If you receive error "Cannot open `Scratch-441.1.exe` file" using 7-zip it means only one thing: your downloaded file is corrupted, download anew using some other downloader or PC etc.